Getting wrong results after performing paired t-test in R
I am trying to perform a paired t-test on the following data:



compound
day
fraction1
fraction2




A
1
3.3
16.5


A
2
1.4
11.2


A
3
2.8
15.3


A
4
0.6
42.4


A
5
0.9
20


A
6
21
43.8


A
7
22
56.5


A
8
1.1
9.6


A
9
2.3
6.5


A
10
0.4
7.1


B
1
1.2
15.4


B
2
1.4
11.4


...
...
...
...


B
10
14.3
18.7



I would like to do the t-test separately for compound A and B.
I tried the following:
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

data <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(compound) %>% 
  do(tidy(t.test(df1$fraction1, 
                 df1$fraction2, 
                 mu = 0, 
                 alt = "two.sided", 
                 paired = TRUE, 
                 conf.level = 0.95)))
data

This ends in this result:
A
 tibble: 2 × 9
# Groups:   compound [2]
  compound estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method        alternative
  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      
1 A           -9.58     -3.47 0.00254        19    -15.3     -3.81 Paired t-test two.sided  
2 B           -9.58     -3.47 0.00254        19    -15.3     -3.81 Paired t-test two.sided  


However, it does not consider the compound A and B, separately.
How do I could achieve a paired t-test for both compounds? Is there also a possibility to see the level of significance (i.e. indicated as ns, *, **, etc.)?
Thanks a lot!

It is very unclear what your objectives in this analysis are, and what your research question(s) is/are. But to answer the question as is, then to perform a paired t-test separately for each compound and get the level of significance indicated as ns, *, **, etc., you need to ensure that the t.test function is applied within each group of the compound variable. The issue with your current approach is that the t.test is being applied to the entire dataset instead of within each group. Here's how you can achieve this using dplyr and broom:
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# Example data frame
df1 <- data.frame(
  compound = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
  day = rep(1:10, 2),
  fraction1 = c(3.3, 1.4, 2.8, 0.6, 0.9, 21, 22, 1.1, 2.3, 0.4, 1.2, 1.4, 2.8, 0.6, 0.9, 21, 22, 1.1, 2.3, 14.3),
  fraction2 = c(16.5, 11.2, 15.3, 42.4, 20, 43.8, 56.5, 9.6, 6.5, 7.1, 15.4, 11.4, 15.3, 42.4, 20, 43.8, 56.5, 9.6, 6.5, 18.7)
)

# Perform paired t-test separately for each compound
result <- df1 %>%
  group_by(compound) %>%
  do(tidy(t.test(.$fraction1, 
                 .$fraction2, 
                 mu = 0, 
                 alt = "two.sided", 
                 paired = TRUE, 
                 conf.level = 0.95)))

# Function to add significance level
add_significance <- function(p.value) {
  if(p.value < 0.001) {
    return("***")
  } else if(p.value < 0.01) {
    return("**")
  } else if(p.value < 0.05) {
    return("*")
  } else {
    return("ns")
  }
}

# Add significance level to the result
result <- result %>%
  mutate(significance = sapply(p.value, add_significance))

print(result)

which results in this:
# A tibble: 2 × 10
# Groups:   compound [2]
  compound estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method        alternative significance
  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>       
1 A           -17.3     -4.41 0.00170         9    -26.2     -8.43 Paired t-test two.sided   **          
2 B           -17.2     -4.31 0.00195         9    -26.2     -8.18 Paired t-test two.sided   **          

The paired t-test is appropriate for comparing two related groups, such as fraction1 and fraction2 measurements for each day within each compound. This test assumes that the differences between paired observations are normally distributed. While the sample size of 10 observations per compound is (just about) reasonable for a t-test, interpreting results from small samples requires caution.
Additionally, performing multiple t-tests increases the risk of Type I errors (false positives), necessitating adjustments for multiple comparisons using methods like the Bonferroni correction. Reporting confidence intervals alongside p-values provides valuable information about the precision of the estimates. Visualising the data using paired scatter plots or Bland-Altman plots can offer further insights into the relationship between fraction1 and fraction2.
It might be possible to model the data using a single mixed-effects regression model. A mixed-effects model can account for both fixed effects, which are consistent across observations, and random effects, which capture variability within groups, such as different compounds. This approach can handle correlations within paired observations and between groups effectively. However without knowing a lot more about the data and research questions I hesitate to say much more about that now.
